# How much will removing a bedroom affect my home's value?

Tags: remodeling, renovation, design, architecture

I recently purchased a 4br 2ba split level house, brand new construction. The trouble I am having is that there is no "master suite" in the house.

If I remove one bedroom and modify the space on my main level to have: a bedroom, walk-in closet, a private bathroom and a toilet/sink (water closet is what we call them), would it positively or negatively affect my home's value?

I would love to be able to stretch out a bit and have more of a retreat for my wife and I, but I also don't want to wreck the home's value.

Thank's for your input!

Comment: It depends. 4>3 isn't as detrimental as 3>2. If all the rooms are tiny and undesirable it could add value if done well. If there's only 2 br on main floor and you're removing one, that might be a problem for parents wanting to sleep closer to a baby or young child. Maybe you could make a small office (aka nursery) that counted as a br instead of a huge closet or master bath suite; you would still get a bigger br...

Answer (score 2):

If all you are talking about is removing some walls and doors (if they aren't structural components) then the value impact will depend on your local market, but the impact will not be more than the cost to restore the walls when sale is planned.